# How use Appengine Blobstore (with Android)?

Tags: google-app-engine, blobstore

I would like to updload and get pictures from my android application using the appengine Blobstore. I have some issue. I think that I didn't understand very well the process of the blobstore.

Here it's what I have done:

**In my client side** (Android) I just call an URL (api/pictures/upload/) and post my picture as an array of bytes (byte[]). I think that my client side is good.

**In my server side** (using appengine in java with Jersey) here is my webservice :

**- Upload Web Service :** (this function is called directly by android)

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response uploadImageBis(@Context HttpServletRequest req, @Context HttpServletResponse res) throws IOException{

    BlobstoreService bs = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
    bs.createUploadUrl("/upload");
    Map<String, List<BlobKey>> blobFields = bs.getUploads(req);
    List<BlobKey> blobKeys = blobFields.entrySet().iterator().next().getValue();
    if (blobKeys != null && !blobKeys.isEmpty()) {
        BlobKey blobKey = blobKeys.get(0);
        System.out.println("MY KEY: "+blobKey.getKeyString());
    }

    return null;
}
```

The line "      BlobstoreService bs = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
" create an error : **Must be called from a blob upload callback request**
But after a while it is persist (in the datastore or blobstore) and when I check my datastore there is a new tab created called : **BlobUploadSession**

Then when I tried to get the picture using the key from the console of google I have this mistake : **Could not find blob: BlobKey:...**  I guess that maybe the picture is store in the dataStore instead of the blobstore??

But I think that I did something wrong in my Upload Web Service. If someone can help me and explain what is wrong it's will be great. 
Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Blobupload on GAE is a two step process:

a. Client requests a one-time upload url:

```
@GET
@Produces("text/plain")
public String uploadImageBis(@Context HttpServletRequest req, @Context HttpServletResponse res) throws IOException{
  BlobstoreService bs = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
  return bs.createUploadUrl("/upload");
}
```

b. Client POSTs multipart data to that Url:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response uploadImageBis(@Context HttpServletRequest req, @Context HttpServletResponse res) throws IOException{

  Map<String, List<BlobKey>> blobFields = bs.getUploads(req);
  List<BlobKey> blobKeys = blobFields.entrySet().iterator().next().getValue();
  if (blobKeys != null && !blobKeys.isEmpty()) {
    BlobKey blobKey = blobKeys.get(0);
    System.out.println("MY KEY: "+blobKey.getKeyString());
  }

  return null;
}
```

Comment: Thx for your response. But I don't understant the link between the a and b. My client need to call the web service a or the b? Sorry but I am confused.

Comment: Have I to call first the a for get the upload url and then put this url in my request with my picture and call the b?

Comment: Thx Martin for you help! I implemented this, I got the good url for upload but after I have this mistake again : Must be called from a blob upload callback request. It is the same mistake than before.